# ER Diagram: Table that is not connected to any other table

Tags: sql-server, entity-relationship, erd

I am looking at an ER Diagram put together several years ago. There is a table in the diagram that is not connected to any other table.

What purpose does this table serve / what could it be used for?

I tried searching Stackoverflow and Google, but nobody actually answers this question.

**Edit #1: Clarification**

I am under the impression that all tables have to be connected in some way in an ER diagram and if they are not, something is wrong.

Comment: How could anybody possibly answer this? You should look in the system and try to determine what purpose it serves. Sometimes tables have no defined relationship and it is only a logical relationship. That isn't a good design model but it does happen.

Comment: I meant in the general sense. I.e. I thought all tables had to be related in an ER diagram to each other in some way.

Comment: It could be an audit table or some other kind of table for holding data that doesn't need a relationship. Possibly just a poor design where they missed establishing a defined relationship.

Comment: But not everything *has* to be connected. It just has to be related to the entity in some way?

Comment: I don't know I didn't write that ERD. There is nothing about an ERD that says that every table must be related to another. Those types of relationships are things like foreign keys. A table can exist without any foreign keys in either direction and still be needed by an application. Often if they are not connected than a relationship might have been missed in the design phase. But some tables like audit table shouldn't have a relationship or it would prevent deleting data.

Comment: Correct, you didn't write that ERD. I am talking about ERD concepts in general, not for a particular one. What I am trying to ask you is why would ANYONE FOR ANY ER DIAGRAM include a table that is not connected. 

I figured it out after asking someone more senior than myself. I will post the response shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spoke with someone more senior than I am and this is how they explained it to me:

> Let's pretend I am building an ER diagram for a restaurant.
>
> I have 3 tables:
>
> 1. Orders
> 2. Employees
> 3. Inventory
>
> These are all in the same ER diagram. Tables 1 and 2 are connected,
>   but nothing is connected to table 3.
>
> Tables do not all have to be connected in an ER Diagram, but there has
>   to be a purpose for having it there.
>
> If we are creating an ERD to show seating availability, having table 3
>   would not make any sense as it is not relevant.
>
> If we are designing the whole restaurant set of processes, then you
>   can have stuff that isn't connected as they will obviously be part of
>   their own contained processes.

**TLDR:** Not all tables have to be connected in an ER diagram, but all
tables should relate to the same set of processes.

Comment: `Tables do not all have to be connected in an ER Diagram, but there has to be a purpose for having it there.`
Unless it was added by mistake. It happens. I've done it. And if it's big enough and complicated enough, it would go unnoticed.